# Perl: "No such file or directory" when executed with parameters

Tags: linux, perl, debian, cgi-bin

All my perl programs have suddenly produced 500 errors when executed in the cgi-bin of a website. They were working fine last week.

When executing from the command line *"perl program.pl"* works correctly. However when any program is executed with paremeters eg *"perl program.pl?param1=xxxx"* I get *"No such file or directory"*

It looks as though Perl or the system is seeing the program & parameters as the filename and not parsing the part before the '?'. I have changed nothing but I did have a crash this week which may have disrupted perl in some way. But I have no idea where or what to look for.

Perl is running under Debian Jessie on an ISPConfig setup. PHP is working just fine. File permissions are ok (or I wouldn't be able to execute the bare program).

Comment: `?` is part of URL syntax, it can't be used on the Linux command line. The shell thinks it's part of the filename.

Answer (score 4):

> *However when any program is executed with paremeters eg "`perl program.pl?param1=xxxx`" I get "`No such file or directory`".*

As you should, and as it always has been.

`perl` is used to execute Perl scripts. As such, it needs to be provided the path to a Perl script. There's no reason for it to accept URLs. Arguments to pass to the Perl script can be passed as additional arguments to `perl`.

```
$ cat >script.pl
print "Received ".( 0+@ARGV )." arguments.\n";
print "$_: $ARGV[$_]\n" for 0..$#ARGV;
^D

$ perl script.pl abc def     
Received 2 arguments.
0: abc
1: def
```

Perhaps you are trying to execute a Perl script as a CGI script. That would require actually obeying the CGI protocol when launching Perl, something you aren't doing. The most common way of doing that is to launch it via a web server, the intended parent of a CGI program.

> *All my perl programs have suddenly produced 500 errors*

The first thing to do is check the web server's error log to see what error is causing the web server to return an error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ikegami's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31596114/7231), it's worth pointing out that if your CGI programs are written using [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI), then they already have built-in support for running them on the command line for debugging purposes. You just need to to omit the `?` in your call.

```
perl program.pl param1=xxxx
```

This passes the parameter `param1=xxxx` to your program and CGI.pm will simulate that information being passed in through a standard CGI environment.